# Why running .Net Regex with ECMAScript flavor support \A

Tags: c#, .net, regex, ecma

I have a `.NetStandard2.1` `C#` application that needs to run `Regex` in the `ECMAScript` flavor.

According to [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=net-5.0), I can use `RegexOptions.ECMAScript`:

> Enables ECMAScript-compliant behavior for the expression.

I know that `\A` anchor is not supported in `ECMAScript` (According to [link](https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6c933f4a7d713ef712145c5eb94a1816) and when I tried [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) with the ECMAScript option). But it seems that .Net does support it. Example:

```
Regex emcaRegex = new Regex(@"\A\d{3}", RegexOptions.ECMAScript);
var matches =  emcaRegex.Matches("901-333-");

Console.WriteLine($"number of matches: {matches.Count}"); // number of matches: 1
Console.WriteLine($"The match: {matches[0]}"); // The match: 901
```

I expect to get not matches at all, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look for the answer further in the ["ECMAScript Matching Behavior" article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options#ecmascript-matching-behavior).

This option *does NOT* redefine the .NET-specific anchors meanings, they are still supported.

> The behavior of ECMAScript and canonical regular expressions differs in three areas: character class syntax, self-referencing capturing groups, and octal versus backreference interpretation.
>
> Character class syntax. Because canonical regular expressions support Unicode whereas ECMAScript does not, character classes in ECMAScript have a more limited syntax, and some character class language elements have a different meaning. For example, ECMAScript does not support language elements such as the Unicode category or block elements `\p` and `\P`. Similarly, the `\w` element, which matches a word character, is equivalent to the `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` character class when using ECMAScript and `[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}\p{Lm}]` when using canonical behavior. For more information, see [Character Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions).
>
> Self-referencing capturing groups. A regular expression capture class with a backreference to itself must be updated with each capture iteration.
>
> Resolution of ambiguities between octal escapes and backreferences.

| Regular expression | Canonical behavior | ECMAScript behavior |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `\0` followed by 0 to 2 octal digits | Interpret as an octal. For example, `\044` is always interpreted as an octal value and means "$". | Same behavior. |
| `\` followed by a digit from 1 to 9, followed by no additional decimal digits, | Interpret as a backreference. For example, `\9` always means backreference 9, even if a ninth capturing group does not exist. If the capturing group does not exist, the regular expression parser throws an [ArgumentException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentexception). | If a single decimal digit capturing group exists, backreference to that digit. Otherwise, interpret the value as a literal. |
| `\` followed by a digit from 1 to 9, followed by additional decimal digits | Interpret the digits as a decimal value. If that capturing group exists, interpret the expression as a backreference. Otherwise, interpret the leading octal digits up to octal 377; that is, consider only the low 8 bits of the value. Interpret the remaining digits as literals. For example, in the expression `\3000`, if capturing group 300 exists, interpret as backreference 300; if capturing group 300 does not exist, interpret as octal 300 followed by 0. | Interpret as a backreference by converting as many digits as possible to a decimal value that can refer to a capture. If no digits can be converted, interpret as an octal by using the leading octal digits up to octal 377; interpret the remaining digits as literals. |

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As I understand from your answer, if I need to use Regex with ECMAScript flavor in .Net application. The RegexOptions.ECMAScript is not the solution.

Comment: @itaiy .NET uses its own regex engine. It does not work as the ECMAScript regex engine and there is no way to make it work exactly as some other regex engine. I just explained how `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option works.